# CSS is working fine in Firefox but doesn't load in Microsoft edge or Chrome

Tags: html, css, django, firefox, microsoft-edge

While coding in Django i was trying to customize my website with some css but while testing multiple webbrowsers i found out that the css is not being applied in Microsoft or Chrome. But its working in firefox. The css file is loading correctly in all browsers but is not being applied.

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
/* Colors */
$color-primary-white: rgb(1, 240, 240);

/* Colors */
#label1{
  color: red;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 50px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.card {
  width: 24rem;
  height: 36rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card_img {
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}

.card_name {
  position: absolute;
  inset: auto auto 30px 30px;
  margin: 0;
  transition: inset .3s .3s ease-out;
  font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.card_desc {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  max-width: 80%;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-out;
  inset: auto auto 80px 30px;
}

.card_desc {
  inset: auto auto 80px 30px;
}

.card:hover .card_name {
  inset: auto auto 220px 30px;
  transition: inset .3s ease-out;
}

.card:hover .card_desc {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .5s .1s ease-in;
}

.card:hover .card_img {
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in;
  opacity: 1;
}

.material-symbols-outlined {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed&family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />

</head>
<body>

<label for="label1" id="label1">eeee</label>


{% for card in cards %}
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card_img" src="{{card.img.url}}" alt="">
    <div class="card-content">
      <h2 class="card_name" >{{card.name}}</h2>
      <p class="card_desc" >{{card.desc}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}


</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to delete cookies and reloading the site but it is still not working.

Comment: Do you have any error message at the DevTools Console?

Comment: @KendrickLi There are no error messages.

Comment: Please grab static file URL from rendered page, open this URL in separate tab and tell us what you see. You can see css file contents? 404 or 403 error?

Comment: @IvanStarostin When i open it in a new tab i see the whole css file as text. No error

Comment: Then the issue is not related to django setup.

Comment: @3llm3r_ I tried your code but these CSS styles are applied as expected in all browsers. To test that it is not related to Django, you can use a basic HTML+CSS combination without Django.

Comment: @KendrickLi I tried the same code in Vscode with a normal html and css but the issue persists

Comment: @3llm3r_ Would you like to give us some screenshots of different behaviors?